# How do I get rid of the padding in my Sencha Touch 2 toolbar?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, sencha-touch-2

here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/sd1212/awHkT/2/

There is space between the buttons and I don't want that.  I used firebug to try to eliminate the padding.  I thought that the layout class was:

```
 x-inner x-toolbar-inner x-layout-hbox
```

so in my CSS file, I put:

```
.x-inner x-toolbar-inner x-layout-hbox
{
   padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Nothing happened.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean 'the whole toolbar' ? in height or in width ?

Comment: In height, but that might just be the button size..I'll edit so its just about the space in between the buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things wrong here

**CSS Syntax**

`.x-inner x-toolbar-inner x-layout-hbox` is a wrong syntax.

If you have something like this

```
<div class="x-inner">
  <div class="x-toolbar-inner">
    <div class="x-layout-hbox">
```

Then you'd use :

```
.x-inner .x-toolbar-inner .x-layout-hbox
```

or

```
.x-inner > .x-toolbar-inner > .x-layout-hbox
```

If you have something like this :

```
<div class="x-inner x-toolbar-inner x-layout-hbox">
```

Then you'd use :

```
.x-inner.x-toolbar-inner.x-layout-hbox
```

**No padding on .x-inner.x-toolbar-innerx-layout-hbox**

If you inspect the div with these CSS class, you can see in Firebug that there is not defined padding. So setting it again to 0 won't change anything.

**Remove the space between the buttons**

However, buttons have a set padding and margin defined like so :

```
.x-toolbar .x-button {
  margin: 0 .2em;
  padding: .3em .6em;
  height:2.2em // of whatever you want
}
```

So you should override this class if you want to modify it

**Last but not least :  Don't override Sencha Touch CSS classes**

Don't override Sencha Touch CSS classes, use the `cls` the attribute on your toolbar like :

```
cls:'my-toolbar',
```

and then to something like this :

```
.my-toolbar .x-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:2.2em // of whatever you want
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What is the reason or why not override Sencha Touch CSS classes? I don't understand :S

Comment: It's just bad practice. If you override .x-toolbar .x-button then all the buttons in all the toolbars with have this style. So if you want to have a button with another then you'll have to override it again..